# Error AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.2-6503028-windows Daemon

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

When I build apk in Android Studio, it fails with an error like this:

> Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
>
> > Multiple task action failures occurred:
> > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.2-6503028-windows Daemon #57: Daemon startup failed
> > Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> > This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.2-6503028-windows Daemon #56: Daemon startup failed
> > Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> > This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.2-6503028-windows Daemon #58: Daemon startup failed
> > Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> > This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.2-6503028-windows Daemon #59: Daemon startup failed
> > Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> > This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.2-6503028-windows Daemon #60: Daemon startup failed
> > Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> > This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.2-6503028-windows Daemon #61: Daemon startup failed
> > Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> > This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.2-6503028-windows Daemon #62: Daemon startup failed
> > Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> > This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.2-6503028-windows Daemon #63: Daemon startup failed
> > Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> > This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.

Help me resolve this error...

My Android Gradle Plugin version is
`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2'`

Answer (score 0):

This error comes when we update android studio or gradle update.

You can downgrade your gradle version.

- Go to File->Project-Structure->Project
- Change Android Gradle Plugin Version to 3.3.2 or the last stable version for you
- Change the Gradle Version to 4.10.1
- Click Ok and sync

Comment: The method above can't solve my problem, the same error still appears

Answer (score 0):

The error you posted says: "Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime".
So I suggest you to update your Windows Universal C Runtime through Windows Update.

You can also download the right version [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows-c0514201-7fe6-95a3-b0a5-287930f3560c) and install it manually. It helped me.

Answer (score 0):

You can downgrade your gradle version.

1. Go to File-> Project-Structure->Project
2. Change Android Gradle Plugin Version to 3.3.2 or Change the Gradle Version to 5.3 (setting these version solved my issue)
3. Click Ok and Sync